# Flag if the last element in a group contain particular string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have data:

```
Group   string
 A     Hello
 A     SearchListing
 A     GoSearch
 A     pen
 A     Hello
 A     Searches
 B     Real-Estate
 B     Access
 B     Denied
 B     Group
 B     Group
 C     Glance
 C     NoSearch
 C     Home
 C     FullSearch
```

and so on.

I want to find those group which has a string containing "search" as their last element and flag them. For example, the output i want is something like this:

```
  Group   Flag
   A       1
   B       0
   C       1
```

as both A and C had their last element containing string "search".
I know of a method which can iterate through all the elements and if last element contains "search" it will flag it. But its a very heavy function using loops.
Is there a more straight forward way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.contains`:

```
(df.groupby('Group')['string']
   .last()
   .str.contains('search', case=False)
   .astype(int)
   .rename('Flag')
   .reset_index())

  Group  Flag
0     A     1
1     B     0
2     C     1
```

---

Similar to above (make a copy or reset the index to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`).

```
u = df.drop_duplicates('Group', keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)
u['Flag'] = u.pop('string').str.contains('search', case=False).astype(int)
u

  Group  Flag
0     A     1
1     B     0
2     C     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `drop_duplicates` with `contains`

```
yourdf=df.drop_duplicates('Group',keep='last').\
           assign(Flag=lambda x : x['string'].str.contains('Search'))
yourdf
Out[645]: 
   Group      string   Flag
5      A    Searches   True
10     B       Group  False
14     C  FullSearch   True
```

Comment: Let me give it a shot again. Double check it.

Comment: Nevermind my comment, i will delete it. There are cases which contains Research. I think yours is working fine. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
df.groupby('Group')['string'].apply(lambda x: 'search' in x.str.cat().lower()).reset_index(name='Flag')
```

Output:

```
Group   Flag
0   A   True
1   B   False
2   C   True
```

**Speed comparison**

```
%%timeit
df.drop_duplicates('Group',keep='last').\
           assign(Flag=lambda x : x['string'].str.contains('Search'))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.groupby("Group")["string"] \
  .apply(lambda x: int("search" in x.values[-1].lower())) \
  .reset_index(name="Flag")
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('Group')['string'].apply(lambda x: 'search' in x.str.cat().lower()).reset_index(name='Flag')
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop

%%timeit
(df.groupby('Group')['string']
   .last()
   .str.contains('search', case=False)
   .astype(int)
   .rename('Flag')
   .reset_index())
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.14 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
df.groupby("Group")["string"] \
  .apply(lambda x: int("search" in x.values[-1].lower())) \
  .reset_index(name="Flag")

    Group   Flag
0   A   1
1   B   0
2   C   1
```

Function-wise (per comment below):

```
def last_search(df, word):
    return df.groupby("Group")["string"].apply(lambda x: int(word in x.values[-1].lower())).reset_index(name="Flag")

last_search(df, "search")
    Group   Flag
0   A   1
1   B   0
2   C   1
```

PS

The same could be done with other answers as well

Comment: The other two solutions also have one liners. And `apply` is slow, would not recommend if it can be avoided.

Comment: any idea how to put it into a function and use it?